# $f (x,y) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k\cos(kx)e^{-ky}/k $ is continuous on the points $(x,0)$ for $x \in (0,\pi)$

Tags: real-analysis

I already know that $$f (x,y) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k\cos(kx)e^{-ky}}{k}$$ converges for all $(x,y) \in [0,\pi] \times (0, \infty)$ and, that $f$ is continuous on that region.

Now, I want to show that $f$ is well-defined for $(x,0)$ with $x \in (0,\pi)$ and in fact that $f$ is continuous on those points.

Here's what I was thinking:

I'm trying to use summation by parts to conclude on uniform convergence for all $x \in [a,b]$ for some closed interval $[a,b]$ in $(0,\pi)$, but to do that I need to show uniform convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k\cos(kx)/k$ in that interval which I'm not sure how to do. I know $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k\sin(kx)/k$ converges uniformly on that interval because $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-2)(-1)^k\sin(kx)/k$ is the Fourier expansion of $g(x) = x$ in $[-\pi,\pi]$, but I'm not sure how that helps anything.

Comment: do you want to show that $f$ is continuous as a function of $x$ for any fixed $y$?

Comment: Do you mean $\infty$ rather than $n$?

Comment: yep, i meant infinity, thank you, i corrected it. and no, just usual continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dirichlet's test, which can be proved using summation by parts, establishes uniform convergence. It states that the series $ \sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x) \phi_k(x)$converges uniformly if $\phi_k(x) \to 0$ monotonically and uniformly and the partial sums $\sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x)$  are uniformly bounded for all $n$.

In this case, convergence of $\phi_k(x) = 1/k$ to $0$ is monotonic and trivially uniform for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

The partial sums of $f_k(x) = (-1)^k \cos kx$ are uniformly bounded for $x \in [a,b] \subset (0, \pi)$ with $0 \leqslant a < b < \pi$.

Indeed,

$$\begin{align}\left| \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \cos kx \right| &= \left|\Re \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k e^{ikx }\right| \\ &= \left| \Re\sum_{k=1}^n  e^{ik(x+ \pi) }\right| \\ &= \left|
\Re\frac{e^{i(x + \pi)}- e^{i(n+1)(x + \pi)}}{1 - e^{i(x + \pi)}}\right| \\ &= \left|\frac{1}{2}\left( 1+ \cos [(n+1)(x+ \pi)] + \tan(x/2)\sin [(n+1)(x+ \pi)\right)] \right| \\ &\leqslant 1+\frac{1}{2 \cos(x/2)} \\ &\leqslant 1+\frac{1}{2 \cos(b/2)} \end{align}$$

Comment: lovely, thank you (:

Comment: @violeta: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

For $y \ge 0$ and $0 < x < \pi$,
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{\cos(kx) e^{-ky}}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{e^{k(ix-y)} + e^{k(-ix-y)}}{2k} = -\frac{1}{2} \left( \ln\left(1 + e^{ix-y}\right)+ \ln \left(1 + e^{-ix-y}\right)\right)$$
which is a continuous function of $(x,y) \in (0,\pi) \times [0,\infty)$.